# Why .setHours(0,0,0,0) is resulting in T07:00:00.000Z

Tags: javascript

I need to get start of day and end of day. I have been reading that if I am going to do date stuff to use momentjs. While I might go that route right now I do not think I will need that much date manipulation so am gonna try to not add more npm packages to this project than needed. I was reading that you can set a date to start of day with `.setHours(0,0,0,0)` though when I try this in my terminal I am seeing the hours get set to `T07:00:00.000Z` can someone explain why? Feels like it should be `T00:00:00.000Z`

```js
let date = new Date('2019-08-16T20:30:38Z');
date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: `Z` is (basically) shorthand for UTC.

Comment: try setUTCHours instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I live in the Central timezone, UTC -5 this time of year, so I get T05:00:00.000Z when I run it. Since you live in the Pacific timezone (presumably), UTC -7, you get 7am UTC. You are setting the local time but outputting the time in UTC. From the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

> The setHours() method sets the hours for a specified date according to local time, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance